# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in search_tweets of rtweet library

Tags: r, api, twitter, rtweet

I'm trying to download tweets using the [rtweet](https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet) library of R. However, If I try to download a lot of tweets (like 100k) after some time it throws the error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

This is the line that I'm trying to execute:

```
tweets.df <- search_tweets("messi", n=100000,token=token,retryonratelimit = TRUE, lang = "en",since="2021-08-06", until = "2021-08-10")
```

After it throws the error no tweets are saved into tweets.df variable.

Comment: Can you get 10 tweets? Is it throwing the error for any call?

Comment: Yes, I can get 10 tweets without errors

Comment: It looks like when paginating, curl gets an empty json. What happens if you try it with n = 45000?

Comment: I have tried with 50k and it happens the same. I agree with you that the problem is that it receives a wrong json because I see that it does many downloads before crashing. It says "Rate limit exceeded for Twitter endpoint '/1.1/search/tweets' Waiting for refresh in X minutes"  many times before crashing.

Comment: I would make a dataframe or vector of times in a hourly or few hourly rate and pull in smaller amounts in a loop or apply function. When looking at the Readme it only shows n=10000, so I eould assume you are timing out or exceeding a Twitter api call limit.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it! The problem was that I had an old version of the library and it seems that something has changed since I installed it. So, I run:

```
install.packages("rtweet")
```

And now it is working well!